# Python "setup.py develop": is it possible to create ".egg-info" folder not in source code folder?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

Python has ability to "pseudoinstall" a package by running it's `setup.py` script with `develop` instead of `install`. This modifies python environment so package can be imported from it's current location (it's not copied into `site-package` directory). This allows to develop packages that are used by other packages: source code is modified in place and changes are available to rest of python code via simple `import`.

All works fine except that `setup.py develop` command creates an `.egg-info` folder with metadata at same level as `setup.py`. Mixing source code and temporary files is not very good idea - this folder need to be added into "ignore" lists of multiple tools starting from vcs and ending backup systems.

Is it possible to use `setup.py develop` but create `.egg-info` directory in some other place, so original source code is not polluted by temporary directory and files?

Comment: Out of interest, does ``setupy.py clean`` tidy up the unwanted files after you are done with them?

Comment: @pelson No, ".egg-info" directory created during "setup.py develop" is not affected by "setup.py clean". This is kind of expected, since this directory is not temporary - it's a part of "developer installation".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`setup.py develop` creates a python egg, in-place; it does **not** *[modify the] python environment so package can be imported from it's current location*. You still have to either add it's location to the python search path or use the directory it is placed in as the current directory.

It is the job of the `develop` command to create an in-place egg, which may include compiling C extensions, running the 2to3 python conversion process to create Python3 compatible code, and to provide metadata *other* python code may be relying on. When you install the package as an egg in your `site-packages` directory, the same metadata is included there as well. The data is certainly not temporary (it is extracted from your `setup.py` file for easy parsing by other tools).

The intent is that you can then rely on that metadata when using your package in a wider system that relies on the metadata being present, while still developing the package. For example, in a [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) development deployment, we often use [`mr.developer`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) to automate the process of fetching the source code for a given package when we need to work on it, which builds it as a develop egg and ties it into the deployment while we work on the code.

Note that the `.egg-info` directory serves a specific purpose: to signal to other tools in the setuptools eco-system that your package is installed and available. If your package is a dependency of another egg in your setup, then that dependency is satisfied. `pip` and `easy_install` and buildout will not try and fetch the egg from somewhere else instead.

Apart from creating the `.egg-info` directory, the only *other* thing the command does, is to build extensions, in-place. So the command you are looking for instead is:

```
setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This will do the exact same thing as `setup.py develop` but leave out the `.egg-info` directory. It also won't generate the `.pth` file.

There is no way of generating only the `.pth` file and leave out the `.egg-info` directory generation.

<sup><sub>Technically speaking, `setup.py develop` will also check if you have the setuptools `site.py` file installed to support namespaced packages, but that's not relevant here.</sub></sup>

Comment: Running `build.py develop` also patches .pth files so i can import module / run app on the affected computer. With `setup.py build_ext --inplace` this is not happening: running this command does not register module / app and it can't be imported / executed afterward :(

Comment: @EyeofHell: True, and *only* the `setup.py develop` and `easy_install` commands generate that file.

Comment: @EyeofHell: But why do you object to the `.egg-info` directory but not to the `.pth` files? Both serve specific and important purposes in the Python egg ecosystem.

Comment: `.pth` file is in python's dir and `.egg-info` is in my source code dir. It's a good practice to separate source code from temporary and system files (temp, libs, created executable etc). Of course i can add `.egg-info` dir to `ignore` section of all tools i use, but nowadays lots of tools are used... So if it's some way to dish this `.egg-info` into some python/PYTHONPATH/wahetever dir i will be happy :)

Comment: I have `.egg-info` added to my git ignores (as it was to my svn ignores before, and SublimeText 2 ignores it by default); it's a fact of Python egg development, and it does belong with the code (since that is the exact version it applies to). There is currently *no* way to generate *only* the `.pth` file and not the `.egg-info` directory.

Comment: So where is no way to somehow move this dir out of source code?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. It is always looked for next to the `setup.py` file it was generated from (the top-level dir of the egg; installed eggs don't have the `setup.py` file anymore).

Comment: @EyeofHell: Note that you already have to ignore `*.pyc` files, or, as of Python 3.2, the `__pycache__` subdirectories. The `.egg-info` directory is *not* your only concern when developing Python code.

Comment: `.pyc` files can be ignored globally on developer computers via `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment variable.

Comment: It still feels as if you are stubbornly going against the grain here. Either you set `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` and other work-arounds, *or* you set your tools to ignore `.pyc` and `.egg-info`. Both are one-time configuration changes, but the latter is current practice, not to mention faster in the case of avoiding the constant re-compilation of python code. Why all the trouble, what advantage do you hope to gain?

Comment: Many tools are used in development process. Configuring ignore list for each tool on each development PC is a huge task. So i'm minimizing it `where possible` :). It's possible for `.pyc` files so i'm doing it. Not possible for `egg-info` dirs? Ok, i will add them to ignore :)

Comment: @EyeofHell: This is not one such place, I fear. `.egg-info` is not temporary information, `pkg_resources` relies on it being present, for example (entry point loading, etc.).

Comment: I'll throw in with another motivation: tab-completion. I hate typing `ex<tab>` and having it come up with `example`, not `example/`. I know I could do as Christopher suggests, and ["keep all source files inside (a) special directory"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13554020/309233) but, "I don't wanna! _waaah!_" :-)

Comment: Am I missing something or is the statement *it does not [modify the] python environment so package can be imported from it's current location.* is just plain wrong taking into consideration that egg-link file is created just so installed package could be imported?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm another of those odd people who tries to keep my _workspace_ _clean_.  There are good reasons to apart from workmanship: it keeps my working set small so that I can use a robust and efficient backup process. You claim it's going against the grain; I claim it's resisting cargo-cult laziness.  We have ~/.cache, ~/.config, /tmp and the like for good reasons.

Comment: @avdd: the config is *not temporary*, so `tmp` is the wrong place. Python installations aim to be independent, making a central location like a hidden dir in the homedirectory unworkable. Those locations also go counter to being able to install Python packages as a system user to be used by regular users of the OS.

Answer (score 4):

The good manner is to keep all source files inside special directory which name is your project name (programmers using other languages keep their code inside `src` directory). So if your `setup.py` file is inside `myproject` directory then you should keep the files at `myproject/myproject`. This method keeps your sources separated from other files regardless what happen in main directory.

My suggestion would be to use whitelist instead of blacklist -- tell the tools to ignore all files excluding these which are inside `myproject` directory. I think that this is the simplest way not to touch your `ignore` lists too often.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `--install-dir` option. You may also want to use `--build-dir` to change building dir.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working: both are ignored if `develop` is used :(.

Comment: Seems like you are using setuptools, not distutils - there is no `develop` command in distutils. According to code, `develop` command accepts parameter `--egg-path=`, which should do what you want

Comment: I can't comprehend what '--egg-path' do but it's not working too, any vlue raises "error: --egg-path must be a relative path from the install directory" error :(

Comment: Path `../../outside/of/project/root` removes tmpfiles from project and still relative.

Comment: Same error "--egg-path must be a relative path from the install directory".

Comment: `--egg-path` only sets where the `.egg-link` file will point *to* when it is being written. It has nothing to do with what the OP wants to achieve.