# Python live dependency installation via pip (PyPI)

Tags: python, pip, distutils, pypi

I want to pull the live version of a package as a dependency of another package I install with pip.

Now, I have already found out [how to install a live version of a package via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185238/easy-install-live-python-libraries-scripts); and that is **not** the question I am asking here.

I'd like to know whether I can pull in a live dependency version (e.g. from the PyPI index) - at present I was only able to set up tarballs via PyPI.

Comment: I have actually no idea of what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: check out my comment on your answer and/or my latest edit.

Comment: Duplicate's answers detail both how to list git repos as dependencies and also downloadable tarballs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `setup.py`, do:

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'a_required_pypi_package',
        'another_package_in_pypi>=minimum_version'
    ]
    ...
)
```

and `pip`, `setup.py install` or `setup.py develop` will take care of it.

However the requirement will be considered satisfied, if any version of `a_required_pypi_package` is installed. This is especially true, if you use `pip freeze` to write a `requirements.txt` and use it to install packages.

Comment: how would this differ from just specifying a package for which pip will then pull in the newest version? PyPI hosts tarballs for each packagem how do I tell pip to not download those but rather from the PKG-INFO `Download-url:`?

Comment: Now I do not understand at all.`DDownload-url` is the url to download this very package version, not "latest". See [PEP0314](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/)

Comment: Ok, so apparently I can't use Download-url then? I want to have a live package, as simple as that, which I can pull as a dependency via pip. A live package is not pulled from a tarball uploaded somewhere, but directly from the source code in development (in my case at a github url).